# JIRA JQL: search all issues where two fields have identical value

Tags: jira, jql

At our company we have a custom field in our JIRA that tracks who verified an issue (it is a single user selector). Now I would like to find all issues that are assigned to and verified by the same person.

I tried this JQL

```
project = OURPROJECT AND assignee = verifier
```

but I get the following error message:

```
The value 'verifier' does not exist for the field 'assignee'.
```

I need to check against another field's value by reference.

I guess I am not the only one looking for this but I was surprised I could not find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with JQL out of the box.

You can extend JQL with additional JQL functions though. So you could add it yourself if you're able/willing to write code. The 2 most common ways to do this are:

- writing your own custom add-on and implement your own JQL function. See [this tutorial](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/guides/search/tutorial-adding-a-jql-function-to-jira) for an example.
- use the [Script Runner add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/cloud/overview) and implement a custom JQL function in Groovy. See [the documentation for examples](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/4.3.3/jira/custom-jql-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Syntax: CustomFieldName Alias: cf[CustomFieldID] Examples:
>
> Find issues where the value of the "Location" custom field is "New
>   York":
>
> location = "New York"
>
> Find issues where the value of the custom field with ID 10003 is "New
>   York":
>
> cf[10003] = "New York"
>
> Find issues where the value of the "Location" custom field is "London"
>   or "Milan" or "Paris":
>
> cf[10003] in ("London", "Milan", "Paris")
>
> Find issues where the "Location" custom field has no value:
>
> location != empty

So if I were you I'd try "custom field = something"; For example:

```
project = OURPROJECT AND verifier = assignee
```

alternatively try the alias

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-fields-reference-764478339.html#Advancedsearching-fieldsreference-customCustomfield

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response, but this does not help: the error message stays the same: "The value 'assignee' does not exist for the field 'verifier'." The problem is that it expects a value on the right side of the comparison. But I need to reference the issue's own field.

Comment: I also tried the alias (in my case `cf[11401]`). But the error stays the same nonetheless: `The value 'assignee' does not exist for the field 'cf[11401]'.`

Comment: is assignee AND verifier custom fields? have you actually made sure that both custom fields exists and is populated?

Comment: Yes, I made sure of this. And I also tried this with non-custom (= built-in) fields. assignee = reporter does also not work. I think @GlennV is right and therefore I accepted his answer.